# Assignment always make copying in swift

Tags: swift, assign

```
var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var list2 = list1
list2.removeLast()
println(list1)
println(list2)
```

This is a simple code that just:

1. assign the list1 to list2
2. remove object from list2
3. that object is removed from list2 **BUT STILL EXIST IN list1**

It seems that the assignment make something like copying but not assign the pointer.

I want to know if there is any official documents explain about it and how to make it `enter code here`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An array is a struct, and structs are value types, so they are copied by value and not by reference.
The same happens for dictionaries, a copy is created if you assign to another variable.

Classes instead are reference types, and assignment copies the reference to the instance.

You can read more about that in [Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_145)

Sidenote: a struct passed to a function is immutable - you cannot modify it within the function, unless you pass it by reference using the `inout` attribute

Comment: This explains about documentation but doesn't answer about how to make it work!

Comment: @NeerajNama well the OP is asking _I want to know if there is any official documents explain about it and how to make it_.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Apple Swift documentation explains that Swift array (dictionary as well) is a struct, not an object and struct are copied when they are passed around in the code. If you create struct they are always copied. If you want to pass it by reference instead you should create class.

Answer (score 1):

There is an important note in the documentation that the other comments/answers have missed:

At the bottom of [Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_145):

> NOTE
>
> The description above refers to the “copying” of strings, arrays, and
> dictionaries. The behavior you see in your code will always be as if a
> copy took place. However, Swift only performs an *actual* copy behind
> the scenes when it is absolutely necessary to do so. Swift manages all
> value copying to ensure optimal performance, and you should not avoid
> assignment to try to preempt this optimization.

So while you should always treat assignment and such as a 'copy', it sort of isn't unless it really needs to be, so don't try to 'optimize around it' unless you are sure you need to.